# "Noise" in image

Tags: qt, model-view

I use Qt to create a data files managed application. 
I use dialog Model-View QTreeView to show tree structure. 
On Win# it works fine. On Linux sometimes I get following "noise":

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/268/bugloader.jpg/

The noise is shown only if user open several (more then 4) expansion levels.
Any one could help me?

Comment: Wow, that's horrendous.  What desktop are you using, and are you using any stylesheets or custom `QStyle`s?

Comment: I use stylesheet:
background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:1, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0.131, stop:0 rgba(216, 216, 216, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));

If I comment the string then it works properly. Looks like bug with gradients...

Comment: It looks like win app launched in WINE on linux

Comment: This is not noise, it is straight up rendering corruption. Result of a broken implementation and/or particular incompatibility.

Answer (score 0):

You must recompile your Qt application in linux, and then run it, but not run `.exe` by `wine`.

Or else, you have problems with your video card in linux.